# InputMismatchException on Scanner.nextInt

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I'm trying to use a Scanner to draw a rectangle in JFrame, but get these errors:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at DrawerAutoRect.main(DrawerAutoRect.java:39)
```

My goal of this program is to choose the type of object to draw i.e.: lines, rectangles,o vals, and then input the parameters, i.e. if it's a rectangle I'm drawing, the input would be `r, 200,200,400,400` and for it to draw a rectangle with those dimensions on the JFrame. Then I'd just type "end" and it'd end waiting for objects to be input and drawn.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawerAutoRect extends JFrame {
    public DrawerAutoRect(){
    setSize(1020,1020);
}

public static void paint(Graphics g, int a, int b,int c, int d)
{
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
   g2.drawRect(a, b, c, d);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x1 = 100;
    int x2 = 100;
    int y1 = 50;
    int y2 = 50;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String dim = s.next();
    while(dim!="end"){
        if(dim.equals("r")){
            x1 = s.nextInt();
            y1 = s.nextInt();
            x2 = s.nextInt();
            y2 = s.nextInt();
        }
    }
    paint(null, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    DrawerAutoRect r = new DrawerAutoRect();
    r.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    r.setVisible(true);
    //r.pack();
    r.setTitle("Tutorial");
}
```

Comment: From stack trace: ` at DrawerAutoRect.main(DrawerAutoRect.java:39)` What's on the line 39 in `DrawerAutoRect.java`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your input does not only contain the tokens you're looking for, but also **commas** and **spaces**, apparently.

Thus, you have to tell your `Scanner` to use a specific **delimiter** to understand that he has to **tokenise** your input stream on this `String`.

I'd recommend you to use the following **regex** as a delimiter for your `Scanner`:

```
,\s*|\s+
```

This would split your input on:

- any comma, followed by eventually some spaces, or
- at least one space.

Consider this sample code:

```
try (final Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    s.useDelimiter(",\\s*|\\s+");

    String dim;
    do {
        dim = s.next();
        if (dim.equals("r")) {
            System.out.println(s.nextInt());
            System.out.println(s.nextInt());
            System.out.println(s.nextInt());
            System.out.println(s.nextInt());
        }
    } while (!dim.equals("end"));
}
```

Just by entering:

```
r 1, 2, 3, 4, end
```

... on the console, I got the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

... It works!

Also, as a side note, I'd like to point out that, in order to compare `String`s  in **Java**, you should use the `String#equals` method, and not the primitive comparators.

Thus, you should use (as I did in my sample code) `!dim.equals("end")` instead of `dim != "end"`.